# AssertionError when comparing pd DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, assertion

I'm developing a test for a function that I created. My function returns a pandas DataFrame and my test consists in comparing it with a csv file that is stored. I'm using the following script to do so. When I run it, I get `AssertionError` with no other message.

```
rates_over = get_rates_over(args)
gabarito = pd.read_csv(f'{ROOT_DIR}/data/static/rates_over_teste.csv', parse_dates=['date'])
assert rates_over.equals(gabarito)
```

But I suspected that my function was good, so I did the following and it didn't print anything, showing that my intuition was right. What is happening?

```
for index, row in gabarito.iterrows():
    if not row.equals(rates_over.iloc[index]):
        print('Not equal!')
```

EDIT: As suggested by @gallen, here is a print for type and head of both `gabarito` and `Rates_over`.

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a small sample of the data from each `gabarito` and `rates_over`?

Answer (score 2):

A DataFrame is **never** equal to a Series.

#### `pd.DataFrame.equals`

> This function allows two Series or DataFrames to be compared against each other to see if they have the same shape and elements.

It is meant to compare a **DataFrame with a DataFrame**, or a **Series with a Series**, not a mixture of a Series with a DataFrame.

A Series and a DataFrame have entirely different dimensionality.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'foo': [1,2,3]})
s = df['foo']

print(df.shape)
#(3, 1)
print(s.shape)
#(3,)
```

The first check in the [`equals`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.0.5/pandas/core/internals/managers.py#L1397-L1400) method is to check the dimensionality, so it quickly returns False without ever checking the data.

```
def equals(self, other):
    self_axes, other_axes = self.axes, other.axes
    if len(self_axes) != len(other_axes):
        return False
    #...


len(s._data.axes)
#1
len(df._data.axes)
#2
```

---

If you are *certain* your DataFrame only has a single column, then you can `squeeze` it before comparing with your Series.

```
df.squeeze().equals(s)
#True
```

Alternatively convert your Series to a DataFrame using the Series name.

```
df.equals(s.to_frame(s.name))
#True
```

Comment: I've marked your answer as useful, but it wasn't exactly what I was asking. I fixed the title so that other people don't misunderstand as well. I've added a print that shows that both elements compared are dataframes.

Comment: I see. My guess is a floating point inaccuracy then. You can try using numpy.is_close